# How can I import from "SQL View" to Sqoop Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I can import SQL tables to Hive, however when I try to SQL view, I am getting errors.
Any ideas ?

Comment: First idea: provide some more details about code and tools you use and errors you get

Comment: command
`sqoop import  --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://Ipaddressx:1433;username=userx;password=passwordx;database=**databasex**' --table tablex --hive-import`

Error
 _Error during import: No primary key could be found for table **databasex**. Please specify one with --split-by or perform a sequential import with '-m 1'._

Answer (score 0):

From Sqoop [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_parallelism):

```
If your table has no index column, or has a multi-column key, then you must also manually choose a splitting column.
```

I think it's your case here. Provide additional option like:

```
--split-by tablex_id
```

where tablex_id is a field in your view that can be used as a primary key or index.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any special command to import View form RDBMS.

Use simple import command with --split-by that sqoop refers to same as primary key.

Answer (score 0):

you can import the rdbms views data but u have to pass -m 1 or --split-by  in your command.